# Can't center align values in table header in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, center

I am trying to center align the values for my table header cells 'cow' and 'heifer'. Programatically I have already done this for the table rows, but for some reason it won't do this for the header rows. I'm doing this for each individual cell because I don't want the first column 'measurements' to be centered. If you look at the code below you can see I have added a horizontalalign to the tableheadercell for 'cow', but it doesn't show up as centered.

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Width="1050px" Visible="True" GridLines="Both">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow BackColor="Black" ForeColor="Silver" Font-Bold="True">
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Measurements</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell HorizontalAlign="Center">Cow</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Heifer</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    </asp:Table>
```

[image]

Is it something obvious I am doing wrong?

It's the same as what they do in this link at W3schools - http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_tablecell_horizontalalign.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine. That behavior could be caused by CSS contamination, the browser you're using or the DOCTYPE.

Sometimes HTML pages get so complex that rendering issues are hard to track and the solution relies on some tweaks on the code behind.

Try to add the following code on the code behind:

```
Table1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Attributes.Add("style", "text-align:center !important;");
Table1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Attributes.Add("style", "text-align:center !important;");
```

If that does not work can you post more of your code?

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. However, it is slightly annoying that I have to use the code behind to format the layout. Would much rather use CSS. However, that isn't your fault at all. Thanks for the help.